# SQL Server - how to use like keyword in records that have period in the middle of value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below records

[image: example records]

but when i tried to do query `where FullName like '%Gd. Mahendra%'`, it doesn't return any result.

Why ?

it should return the first row, shouldn't it ?

Comment: maybe there are 2 spaces between `Gd.` and `Mahendra`

Comment: Periods don't affect `LIKE`.  You likely have some other unprintable characters in the string (or two spaces between `Gd.` and `Mahendra` - I really can't tell by a picture).

Comment: You can try doing it like this instead:  `WHERE FullName LIKE '%Gd.%Mahendra%'`

Comment: nah, actually there is only 1 space

Comment: try this : where FullName like N'%Gd. Mahendra%' and make sure the string Gd. Mahendra that you provide contains the correct unicode characters

Comment: thanks.. but still doesn't work.

Comment: What if you simplify and simply do `where FullName like '%Mahendra%'`?

Comment: life is not as simply as that. hah..
the case is precisely on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem is:

The value that's been sent by the request is different from the actual record.
It's because the html doesn't use `<pre>` tag, which is able to render multiple spaces. Then the user just copyies the rendered value that doesn't have multiple spaces. That's why it can't get the correct result.

Answer (score 4):

Your comparison *should* be fine:

```
where FullName like '%Gd. Mahendra%'
```

If you suspect the `.`, you can replace it with the single character wildcard:

```
where FullName like '%Gd_ Mahendra%'
```

In general, this type of problem is caused by "invisible" characters or characters that look the same (like zero and a capital O, or a tab and a space, or two spaces).  This can particularly occur with national character sets that extend the basic ASCII characters.

You can see the ASCII value of a character using the `ASCII()`.  That can sometimes help you figure out what is happening.

Comment: actually, i'm using EF. I use Where(x => x.FullName.ToLower().Contains(keywordString.ToLower())), but for some reason it doesn't work. Then i tried to test that in SSMS, but got same result.

Comment: @FatkhanFauzi . . . Use a `'%'` between the words:  `%Gd%Mahendra%`.

Comment: i know.. but in EF there is an issue caused by escape (tilde ~)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   WHERE FullName LIKE '%Gd.%Mahendra%'
```

Comment: that works as Siyual comment's. Do you know how to do that in entity framework ?

Currently, i'm simply using this Where(x => x.FullName.ToLower().Contains(keywordString.ToLower()))